# How can I combine these overlapping render layers?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers

I had this scene:

[image]

Then I broke it into these two render layers:

[image]
[image]

Normally I use an alpha over node to combine render layers, but the transparency and overlapping doesn't allow that in this case. Here are the results of "alpha over" with "one over two" and "two over one".

[image]
[image]

Is there a better way to combine these render layers to get the original back? Or have I broken a rule for what can actually live on separate layers?

Comment: You can combine this using masks in a photo editing program, or by drawing a mask and using it in the compositor. Otherwise, I would probably prefer to render out the two myelin for both axons together, and the both neurons without the covers as your two render layers.

Comment: Are you sure your suggestion for different layers would work? So far, the only way I've been able to recombine them is when the neuron and the myelin are on the same layer as each other (e.g. a neuron/myelin pair per render layer)

Comment: From your first image it doesn't seem like there are any areas where the neurons are above the myelin, which is why I think you can have all the myelin in one layer, and the neurons in another, then combine them with alpha over.

Comment: What about the bit sticking out the end of the cross-section?

Comment: Right, that bit is gonna cause a problem. You can always separate it into a different object and use the object ID mask to perform any post processes on it without affecting the myelin.

Comment: at some point both your objects are in front of each other, so usual "stacking" of layers is not going to work. introducing the ID mask will work i guess, but why do you need them on seperate layers anyway if their entangled in each other?

Comment: Have you tried using the *z-combine* node?

Comment: @blackdot one of them is going to have unhealthy myelin, so I figured getting it on a separate render layer would help me in the compositor (e.g. put a red glow around it, like in all of old back pain commercials)

Comment: @ajwood hmm okay. i'll certainly watch this question :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Render your layers with `Z pass`:
[image: Passes]

Combine them using `Z Combine` node from `Color tab`:

[image: Node editor]

In `Z Combine` node check `Use Alpha` checkbox if needed.